# Send data from one template to another in symfony2

Tags: symfony, twig

I have one twig file named `index.html.twig` as follow:

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="2">

                    <div class="control-group component" rel="popover" title="Search Input" trigger="manual"
                      data-content="
                      <form class='form'>
                        <div class='controls'>
                          <label class='control-label'>Label Text</label> <input class='input-large' type='text' name='label' id='label'>
                          <label class='control-label'>Options: </label>
                          <textarea style='min-height: 200px' id='option'> </textarea>
                          <hr/>
                          <button class='btn btn-info'>Save</button><button class='btn btn-danger'>Cancel</button>
                        </div>
                      </form>"
                      >

                      <!-- Select Basic -->
                      <label class="control-label valtype" data-valtype="label">Select - Basic</label>
                      <div class="controls">
                        <select class="input-xlarge valtype" data-valtype="option">
                          <option>Enter</option>
                          <option>Your</option>
                          <option>Options</option>
                          <option>Here!</option>
                        </select>
                      </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="control-group component" rel="popover" title="Search Input" trigger="manual"
                      data-content="
                      <form class='form'>
                        <div class='controls'>
                          <label class='control-label'>Label Text</label> <input class='input-large' type='text' name='label' id='label'>
                          <label class='control-label'>Options: </label>
                          <textarea style='min-height: 200px' id='option'></textarea>
                          <hr/>
                          <button class='btn btn-info'>Save</button><button class='btn btn-danger'>Cancel</button>
                        </div>
                      </form>"
                      >

                      <!-- Select Multiple -->
                      <label class="control-label valtype" data-valtype="label">Select - Multiple</label>
                      <div class="controls">
                        <select class="input-xlarge valtype" multiple="multiple" data-valtype="option">
                          <option>Enter</option>
                          <option>Your</option>
                          <option>Options</option>
                          <option>Here!</option>
                        </select>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                  </div>

                  <div class="tab-pane" id="3">

                    <div class="control-group component" rel="popover" title="Multiple Checkboxes" trigger="manual"
                      data-content="
                      <form class='form'>
                        <div class='controls'>
                          <label class='control-label'>Label Text</label> <input class='input-large' type='text' name='label' id='label'>
                          <label class='control-label'>Options: </label>
                          <textarea style='min-height: 200px' id='checkboxes'> </textarea>
                          <hr/>
                          <button class='btn btn-info'>Save</button><button class='btn btn-danger'>Cancel</button>
                        </div>
                      </form>"
                      >
                      <label class="control-label valtype" data-valtype="label">Checkboxes</label>
                      <div class="controls valtype" data-valtype="checkboxes">

                        <!-- Multiple Checkboxes -->
                        <label class="checkbox">
                          <input type="checkbox" value="Option one">
                          Option one
                        </label>
                        <label class="checkbox">
                          <input type="checkbox" value="Option two">
                          Option two
                        </label>
                      </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="control-group component" rel="popover" title="Multiple Radios" trigger="manual"
                      data-content="
                      <form class='form'>
                        <div class='controls'>
                          <label class='control-label'>Label Text</label> <input class='input-large' type='text' name='label' id='label'>
                          <label class='control-label'>Group Name Attribute</label> <input class='input-large' type='text' name='name' id='name'>
                          <label class='control-label'>Options: </label>
                          <textarea style='min-height: 200px' id='radios'></textarea>
                          <hr/>
                          <button class='btn btn-info'>Save</button><button class='btn btn-danger'>Cancel</button>
                        </div>
                      </form>"
                      >
                      <label class="control-label valtype" data-valtype="label">Radio buttons</label>
                      <div class="controls valtype" data-valtype="radios">

                        <!-- Multiple Radios -->
                        <label class="radio">
                          <input type="radio" value="Option one" name="group" checked="checked">
                          Option one
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio">
                          <input type="radio" value="Option two" name="group">
                          Option two
                        </label>
                      </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="control-group component" rel="popover" title="Inline Checkboxes" trigger="manual"
                      data-content="
                      <form class='form'>
                        <div class='controls'>
                          <label class='control-label'>Label Text</label> <input class='input-large' type='text' name='label' id='label'>
                          <textarea style='min-height: 200px' id='inline-checkboxes'></textarea>
                          <hr/>
                          <button class='btn btn-info'>Save</button><button class='btn btn-danger'>Cancel</button>
                        </div>
                      </form>"
                      >
                      <label class="control-label valtype" data-valtype="label">Inline Checkboxes</label>

                      <!-- Multiple Checkboxes -->
                      <div class="controls valtype" data-valtype="inline-checkboxes">
                        <label class="checkbox inline">
                          <input type="checkbox" value="1"> 1
                        </label>
                        <label class="checkbox inline">
                          <input type="checkbox" value="2"> 2
                        </label>
                        <label class="checkbox inline">
                          <input type="checkbox" value="3"> 3
                        </label>
                      </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="control-group component" rel="popover" title="Inline radioes" trigger="manual"
                      data-content="
                      <form class='form'>
                        <div class='controls'>
                          <label class='control-label'>Label Text</label> <input class='input-large' type='text' name='label' id='label'>
                          <label class='control-label'>Group Name Attribute</label> <input class='input-large' type='text' name='name' id='name'>
                          <textarea style='min-height: 200px' id='inline-radios'></textarea>
                          <hr/>
                          <button class='btn btn-info'>Save</button><button class='btn btn-danger'>Cancel</button>
                        </div>
                      </form>"
                      >
                      <label class="control-label valtype" data-valtype="label">Inline radios</label>
                      <div class="controls valtype" data-valtype="inline-radios">

                        <!-- Inline Radios -->
                        <label class="radio inline">
                          <input type="radio" value="1" checked="checked" name="group">
                          1
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio inline">
                          <input type="radio" value="2" name="group">
                          2
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio inline">
                          <input type="radio" value="3">
                          3
                        </label>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                  </div>

                  <div class="tab-pane" id="4">
                    <div class="control-group component" rel="popover" title="File Upload" trigger="manual"
                      data-content="
                      <form class='form'>
                        <div class='controls'>
                          <label class='control-label'>Label Text</label> <input class='input-large' type='text' name='label' id='label'>
                          <hr/>
                          <button class='btn btn-info'>Save</button><button class='btn btn-danger'>Cancel</button>
                        </div>
                      </form>"
                      >
                      <label class="control-label valtype" data-valtype="label">File Button</label>

                      <!-- File Upload -->
                      <div class="controls">
                        <input class="input-file" id="fileInput" type="file">
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="control-group component" rel="popover" title="Search Input" trigger="manual"
                      data-content="
                      <form class='form'>
                        <div class='controls'>
                          <label class='control-label'>Label Text</label> <input class='input-large' type='text' name='label' id='label'>
                          <label class='control-label'>Button Text</label> <input class='input-large' type='text' name='label' id='button'>
                          <label class='control-label' id=''>Type: </label>
                          <select class='input' id='color'>
                            <option id='btn-default'>Default</option>
                            <option id='btn-primary'>Primary</option>
                            <option id='btn-info'>Info</option>
                            <option id='btn-success'>Success</option>
                            <option id='btn-warning'>Warning</option>
                            <option id='btn-danger'>Danger</option>
                            <option id='btn-inverse'>Inverse</option>
                          </select>
                          <hr/>
                          <button class='btn btn-info'>Save</button><button class='btn btn-danger'>Cancel</button>
                        </div>
                      </form>"
                      >
                      <label class="control-label valtype" data-valtype="label">Button</label>

                      <!-- Button -->
                      <div class="controls valtype"  data-valtype="button">
                        <button class='btn btn-success'>Button</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>


                  <div class="tab-pane" id="5" name="textsource">
                    <textarea id="source" class="span6"></textarea>
                  </div>
```

In this div `id="5"`, it is getting the dynamic data. Now I want to transfer this textarea of `id="5"`in another twig file named `sub.html.twig`. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

After in Symfony 2.3

```
{{ render(controller( 'BloggerBlogBundle:Comment:new', { 'blog_id': blog.id } )) }}
```

Before Synfony 2.3

```
{% render 'BloggerBlogBundle:Comment:new' with { 'blog_id': blog.id } %}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to render data from Controller, such as

```
              <div class="tab-pane" id="5" name="textsource">
                <textarea id="source" class="span6">{{ yourtext }}</textarea>
              </div>
```

then you can include subtemplate and pass this variable there using `with`

```
{% include 'YourBundle:YourFolder:sub.html.twig' with {'yourTextTwigVariable': yourtext} %}
```

Comment: i want to render data that data from index.html.twig into sub.html.twig. there is no data in sub.html.twig

Answer (score 0):

You have to use import or embed tags:

[import](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/import.html) include content in your template with no-action (do not do any more, just "paint")

```
{% include 'Bundle:Folder:template.html.twig' with {} %}
```

[embed](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/embed.html) load content in your template and execute the controller of the loaded route (more expensive in performance, be carefull)

```
{% embed 'Bundle:Controller:template.html.twig' with {} %}
```

Comment: when i am using %embed then i am getting the error                            Unexpected token "end of template" of value "" ("end of statement block" expected) in AcmeTaskBundle:Default:sub.html.php at line 1